# How to disable button or any listerner

Tags: java, libgdx

I have a few group of actor that contain some texture and button. I have a group that act like modal box that popup , overlay and occupy the whole screen. but I realize the actor that blocked by the modal box is still clickable. **How do I disable it beside setting those 20+ button to untouchable?**

Sample code

```
stage.addActor(slotMachine);
stage.addActor(payTableDialog);

payTableDialog.show();
```

Sample code of Dialog class

```
CustomDialog extends Group{

}
```

Comment: how you created modal box Group?

Comment: @arv its my class that extends Group and added after creation to stage.

Comment: are you defining the size of the your cutomDialoge group at the time of creation?

Comment: @arv No. Thats what I need to define , its works after I set the size to screen width and height

Comment: Use [Dialog](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/Dialog.html) instead of Group

Comment: @Leon  If your problem is solved then accept the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the size of the CutomDialoge Group(modal box) to Screen Size.

```
group.setSize(screenWidth, screenHight);
```